# Why is isElementPresent() not working in my protractor scripts?

Tags: typescript, automation, protractor

I use VS Code for writing TypeScript which eventually compiles to protractor and executes the scripts.

VSCode doesn't seem to be autocompleting `element.isPresent()` or `element.isElementPresent` and this is driving me nuts.

Below is my code.

**helper.ts**

```
import { browser, by, ElementArrayFinder, WebElement, ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

async isElementPresent(element: WebElement): Promise<boolean> {

        expect(await element.isElementPresent().toBe(true));
}
```

I want to check if expandAllLink is present or not by passing it as a parameter to the helper function.

**spec1.ts**

```
expandAllLink: WebElement = element(by.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Expand All')]"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the following:

```
let el: ElementFinder = $('cssSelector');
expect(el.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

beacuse `isPresent()` returns `Promise<boolean>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @yong expect(await browser.isElementPresent(ele)).toBe(true); doesn't seem to be returning a Promise<boolean> So I added const abc: Promise<boolean> = expect(await browser.isElementPresent(await element)).toBe(true).then(function() { return true; }); return abc; but this is returning true even if the element doesn't exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues found in your code.

1) [isElementPresent](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.isElementPresent) is the function of `browser` object, but `element`.

2) the `expect().toBe()` in your code with unmatched pair of `()`

```
import { browser, by, ElementArrayFinder, WebElement, ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

async isElementPresent(ele: WebElement): Promise<boolean> {
    // below is your code with wrong pair of ()
    expect(await element.isElementPresent().toBe(true));

    // expect().toBe() should return Pormise<null>
    let present = await browser.isElementPresent(ele);
    expect(present).toBe(true);
    return present;

    // if this function is for getting the present state of elment
    // recommend move expect out of this function.

    // if this function is for validating the present state,
    // recommend make function return value to void.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @yong ```expect(await browser.isElementPresent(ele)).toBe(true);``` doesn't seem to be returning a Promise<boolean> So I added ```const abc: Promise<boolean> = expect(await browser.isElementPresent(await element)).toBe(true).then(function() {
            
            return true;
        });
        return abc;``` but this is returning true even if the element doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: I updated the code. But i'm afraid when the expect fail, the return statement won't be executed.

Comment: Is there no way to ```if(expect(present).toBe(true)){return true;}else{return false;}```